# Retrieve remote information through ajax/remote form in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Whats the best way to accomplish the following:

I have a slider, lets say when it's all the way to the left its value is 0 and when it's all the way to the right, its value is 10.

When the mouse is released I want to send the 10 into a function in a model, and instantly return a value from the model back into the view - without refreshing the page.

I can handle the javascript slider, what I'm curious about is how to make a remote form that can accomplish this, and just return the value without posting a new record to the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use ajax in some flavor to send the data to a controller method which will get your model instance from the db and send whatever information you need back to the client

Answer (score 0):

add a js function to send the slider value and receive the response using ajax, for example using jquery:

```
function updateSlider(sliderVal){    
  $.post('/some-url', {value: sliderVal}, function(data) {
    // data here is value returned by the server
  });
}
```

call the above function in mouseup event or something depending how the slider works.

also in your controller use something like render :text => value